# How can I use this Reformer to extract entities from a new sentence?

Tags: transformer, named-entity-recognition, inference, reformer

I have been looking at the NER example with Trax in [this notebook](https://github.com/google/trax/blob/master/trax/examples/NER_using_Reformer.ipynb). However, the notebook only gives an example for training the model. I can't find any examples of how to use this model to extract entities from a new string of text.

I've tried the following:

- Instantiate the model in 'predict' mode. When trying this I get the same error reported in https://github.com/google/trax/issues/556 `AssertionError: In call to configurable 'SelfAttention' (<class 'trax.layers.research.efficient_attention.SelfAttention'>)`
- Instantiate the model in 'eval' mode and then running `model(sentence)` as I would with other models. In this case the instantiation works but I get the following error when running the model: `TypeError: Serial.forward input must be a tuple or list; instead got <class 'numpy.ndarray'>`. Presumably this is because in 'eval' mode the model needs 2 entries passed in rather than one sentence

How can I use this Reformer to extract entities from a new sentence?

Comment: @SauravMaheshkar This is code you contributed to the trax repo. Are you able to help?